# Variations of $f(t)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+t\mathrm{e}^x}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Let $\displaystyle f(t)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+t\mathrm{e}^x}\,\mathrm{d}x$. It is clear that $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$, that $f(t)$ tends to $+\infty$ as $t$ tends to $0$ and that
$f(t)$ tends to $0$ as $t$ tends to $+\infty$.
However, what are the variations of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$?

I have tried to differentiate several times:
$$\forall t\in\mathbb{R}_+^*:\quad f'(t)=-\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^x\ln(x)}{(1+t\mathrm{e}^x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x,$$
but no sign appears clearly beacause of the term with $\ln$. Numerical considerations suggest that $f$ is decreasing on $]0,\alpha]$ and increasing on $[\alpha,+\infty[$ for one $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_+^*$.

Thank you.

Comment: Mathematica gives $f(t)=-\gamma\log(1+1/t)-\frac d{dx}\operatorname{PolyLog}(x,-1/t)\vert_{x=1}$

Comment: And $f(1)=-\ln^2(2)/2$, so that $f$ takes negative values.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f(t)$ can be written under the form:

$$\displaystyle f(t)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\color{red}{e^{-x}}\ln(x)}{\color{red}{e^{-x}}(1+t\mathrm{e}^x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}\ln(x)}{e^{-x}+t}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$f(t)=\dfrac{1}{t}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}\ln(x)}{1+\frac{e^{-x}}{t}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{t^{k+1}}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-(k+1)x}\ln(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Now, use the result (rather classical as a Laplace Transform : see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laplace_Transform_of_Natural_Logarithm)):

$$\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-sx}\ln(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\tfrac{1}{s}(\gamma+\ln s)$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, we get for $f(t)$ an analytical expression justifying the formula given by Wolfram Alpha (see the comment by @TheSimpliFire) under a tractable way for the second term.

Can you continue from here ?

Comment: Thank you for the hint, it enables me to show that $f$ is increasing on $[1,+\infty[$, but the behaviour of $f$ on $]0,1]$ seems to be harder to handle.